# How do I get the number of affected rows after an update using Sequel?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby, sequel

Is it possible to get the number of affected rows, after updating data?

Here a example:

```
count = table_products.where(:status => 1).update(:status => 0) # is sth like this possible?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it? Docs say that [`update`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#M000370) actually returns the number of affected rows:

> The returned value is generally the
>   number of rows updated, but that is
>   adapter dependent.

I don't have MySQL to check whether it actually works, but if it doesn't, I guess it's up to MySQL, not Sequel.

Comment: Correct, Sequel attempts to return the count of changed rows, but that is dependent on the database driver.